# slowing down internet speed for local files

Tags: plugins, browser

I want to limit browser internet speed for local files. I want to test my website thats local. Is there any way/tool/extension using which I can set browsing speed to some 56K, 256K etc?

I found tools like netlimiter, speetlimit but they work for remote files.

Comment: For speed test I simply upload my site. Is there any particular reason you are not doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Note that "remote files" can also include "a locally running Apache" or "a locally running nginx". You can just install a server on your local system and then use whatever bandwidth-limiting proxies you want to rate limit your bandwidth to your local web server.